# css not loading in my express app

Tags: css, node.js, express

can anyone pls explain the different instances in which css won't load properly in an express application? I know that for example, using relative paths `css/style.css`instead of absolute paths `/css/style.css` can cause the css to not render properly in my webpages; but I was wondering if there's something else that I don't know of that could also cause such a problem?

here's the html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>View Property</title>
            <!-- Load fonts -->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Alegreya|Amatic+SC|Architects+Daughter|Barrio|Cabin|Dancing+Script|Dosis|Exo+2|Gloria+Hallelujah|Inconsolata|Josefin+Sans|Karla|Source+Code+Pro|Yanone+Kaffeesatz" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
            <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/font-awesome.css" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/../favicon.ico">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/viewProperty.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/search.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/component.css" />
            <!--style -->
              <script src="/js/modernizr.js"></script> <!-- Modernizr -->
        </head>
        <body>
          <header class="main-header">
                <a href="" class="menu-toggle" id="nav-expander"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                <!-- Offsite navigation -->
                <nav class="menu">
                    <a href="#" class="close"> <i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    <h3> <a href="index.html">spacelist</a> </h3>
                    <h5><a data-scroll data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModa3" class="btn button two">Add Property</a></h5>
                    <ul class="nav">
                <li class="cl-effect-1"><a data-scroll href="contactus.html">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li class="cl-effect-1"><a data-scroll data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModa4">About</a></li>
                        <li class="cl-effect-1"><a data-scroll href="#portfolio">Safety</a></li>
                        <li class="cl-effect-1"><a data-scroll href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
                        <li class="cl-effect-1"><a data-scroll href="#privacy">Privacy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            <form class="form-group">
              <div class="search">
                      <input type="text" id="searchBox" class="search__input search-field" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off"/>
                      <button class="fa fa-search search__button"></button>
                <ul id="searchResults" class="term-list hidden"></ul>
                    </div>
            </form>

            <div class="profile">
                <img src="images/opeyemi.jpg" alt="photograph of odedeyi opeyemi" class="profile-photo">
                <a href="#">Opeyemi Odedeyi</a>
                </div>
            </header><!--/.main-header-->

          <section class="viewww">
            <h1>View Your Property</h1>
          </section>
          <section class="body content">

            <div class="container">
              <div class="layout" style="background-image: url(images/test.jpg);"></div>
              <h6>Joy 4 Fame Hostel</h6>
              <div class="price">
                <p>GH₵ 1,000 <span>per Month</span></p>
              </div>
              <div class="lorem">
                <p>Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Proin eget tortor risus. Proin eget tortor risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="btn lass edit">Edit</a> <a class="btn lass view">Details</a>
              </div>
            </div>




          </section>


          <!-- Footer start -->
            <footer class="main-footer">
            <!--  <div class="foot">
                    <span>Icon made by Freepik from www.flaticon.com</span>
                </div>  -->
                <div class="foot2">
                    <span>&copy; spacelist 2017</span>
                </div>
            </footer>
                <!-- Footer end  -->

          <!-- Contact section start -->
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/autoSuggest.js"></script>

          <script src="/js/custom-file-input.js"></script>

          <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

          <!-- Load custom js for theme -->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

also back end js code

```
router.get('/viewProperty/:id', AccessControl.ensureAuthenticated, 
function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.id})
    .populate('properties')
    .then(user => {
      let model = {
        properties: user.properties
      };
      console.log(user);
      res.render('viewProperty', model);
    });
});

//was trying test the issue on different routes below

router.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('viewProperty');
});
```

Comment: Could you include your code? It will allow us to assist you better. In addition, have you mounted a directory of static assets using [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)?

Comment: yes I have `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` my css files are inside a folder called css which is inside the public directory

Comment: Well, in that case, you should post the minimum code to reproduce the issue, and any errors, if applicable. Otherwise, there's not enough detail here to really help.

Comment: sorry about that, I added the code above. I properly added the js and css files to their respective folders and used the `express.static`